# Sometimes I get a bounceback when sending emails in Python using SMTPLIB & DKIMPY - Error: 550 Messages should have one From header, not 0

Tags: python, header, smtplib, dkim

Error Message:

> SMTP error from remote server for TEXT command, host:
> mx10.mailspamprotection.com (x.x.x.x) reason: 550 Messages should have
> one From header, not 0.

Below is the code that creates the message, and DKIM signature etc. Running dkim.verify() returns True. This means that the signature is fine, however I have received one or two bounce backs like the above (Both "mailspamprotection.com") out of 50 emails.

I appreciate this isn't a high percentage but I want to overcome this issue.

```
msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
msg.attach(MIMEText(self.email_text, "plain"))
msg.attach(MIMEText(self.email_html, "html"))

**msg["To"] = self.to_email
msg["From"] = f"{self.from_name} <{self.from_email}>" if self.from_name else self.from_email
msg["Subject"] = self.subject**
msg['Date'] = formatdate()
msg['Message-ID'] = make_msgid(domain=self.sender_domain)

headers = [b'to', b'from', b'subject']

sig = dkim.sign(msg.as_bytes(), self.dkim_selector.encode(), self.sender_domain.encode(), self.dkim_key.encode(), include_headers=headers)

sig = sig.decode()

msg['DKIM-Signature'] = sig[len("DKIM-Signature: "):]

self.msg_data = msg.as_bytes()
```

For more context, here is the source of the email below, with confidential parts replaced with x's

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="===============7989252151031916932==" MIME-Version: 1.0; 
To: xxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.co.uk;
From: xxxxx xxxxxx <xxxxx.xxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.xxxx>;
Subject: Thanks for Engaging with Our Website;
Date: Thu, 4 Jul 2020 17:38:00 -0000 Message-ID: <165780643314.283332.1993923921194087211@xxxxxxx.xxxx>;
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple;
d=xxxxxxx.xxxx; i=@xxxxxxx.xxxx; q=dns/txt; s=xxxxxx;
t=1657806433; h=from : to : subject;
bh=4pT7hDvR8C3Img5078vwzvijt0e+7b0oKT8Lr4shal8=;
b=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
```

As you can see in the source here, we pass the following:

**To:**

**From:**

**Subject:**

We also pass those as "included_headers" so they are part of the DKIM signature, you'll see:

**h=from : to : subject;**

The issue is apparently I have no (0) from headers- that's simply not the case.

What am i missing?

Thanks In Advance!